# Why does browser add bluish and brownish colors to a solid font color?

Tags: website-design, fonts, css, anti-aliasing, subpixel-rendering

I'm wondering why my browser (Firefox) add blue tints on the right and brown tints on the left of a solid grey (#333333) font color as shown in the image below.

[image: color picker tool in Firefox shows bluish and brownish tints added to the solid grey font]

Could somebody explain to me why this happens?

Comment: [Antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)? There are a lot of options related, you can set them using a [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is called [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), or subpixel anti aliasing. Microsoft does something similar for most windows applications.

Your screen consists of colors that are next to each other. If you do a simple sample based anti aliasing you do not get the best possible result. But by leveraging of the knowledge of how the pixels are laid out you can get better results. As you're working with less than a pixels worth of data.

You should be careful with this though. Different monitors have different arrangements for the color emission (hence the tuner mentioned by @PaoloGibellini). Thus if your preparing very high quality screenshots it might be a good idea to turn the subpixel rendering off, or you will get a error 2 times*. Likewise if you take screen captures for print, its best to disable this or your text will look like a smeared rainbow.

<sup>*Once by the monitor, which has one order and once by the picture which has a different order</sup>

Comment: Hey, nothing wrong with smeared rainbows!

Comment: In windwos its called ClearType - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Typography/ClearTypeInfo.aspx and its done at system level, I don't think its actuallz FF doing that.

Comment: @hurda no firefox isn't doing it themselves, you can see it in the options that they are talking of direct draw and that includes clear type. You can globally switch it off if you like.

Comment: A screenshot that contains sub-pixel rendering will not get it re-applied when viewed. It's a function on text and some UI elements, not on all graphics. Also, any print shop worth their salt would convert the black text of such a screenshot to pure black before separating.

Comment: @Logarr no it wont be reapplied, but it will be fixed if the pixel order was different then the error gets done 2 times. I really highly doubt any print shop would go and fix pictures retroactively in this way without a fee. Because it would mean they would have to go forth and do this for each element on different backgrounds (on gray, on white on yellow etc). Its just easier to to disable it before screen capture

Comment: What @Logarr says is right; a good print or prepress designer will treat that text the same way as any other rich black. Turning the clear type on or off will simply give you 2 results: ON) you have a richer black text that will then be converted to pure black and keeps most of its original shape and OFF) you'll have jagged edges with a black-to-gray letter that might need to have its levels adjusted.

Comment: @go-me no. Screen captures do not have the super resolutions available that normal designs do. I mean if you do normal print designs resolutions then its no problem. But if you do print screen captures the resolution to print is so poor that this really makes the characters pop out as rainbow blurry. And so far no prepress has actually ever fixed this for me to acceptable level (we even offered a bounty of 2000€ and they still couldnt do it), something that i could fix myself in lass than 15 seconds will be a nightmare to the prepress. And NO not all screen captures are black on white.

Comment: Any stats on how often do screens use anything but the default RGB? Rotatable screens are an obvious case, but how about unmovable screens? I remember OLPC (and CRTs), but it's quite unusual in construction.

Comment: @JanDvorak [this page](http://www.geometrian.com/programming/reference/subpixelzoo/index.php) lists a few known cases many of them Samsung devices. Theres scarse info but at least where i work there is one BGR monitor. Its rare in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

This is called **subpixel rendering**. The different colours are only visible because the image has been blown up. It will be easier to give an example of white on black.

[image: An explanation of subpixel rendering]

Imagine a one pixel thick white line. On most desktop LCD screens the individual subpixels colours are arranged horizontally. As long as all three colour pixels are turned on we will see a white line one pixel thick - it doesn't matter what order the colours are in. This is what the first two rows show. Using subpixel rendering increases the horizontal resolution of the screen by three times, which is especially helpful when reading horizontal text.

But when you take a screenshot and enlarge it, rather than seeing the subpixels, you see the colours they combine to produce. When our one pixel line is aligned with the pixels you just see a one pixel white line. But if it isn't then you'll see a two pixel thick line made up of two colours. You can see this in person if you are close enough to your screen that you can see the gaps between the pixels - if you're close enough your eyes might not resolve the split pixels together, and you'll see the line as being two pixels wide. But if the screen resolution is high enough then subpixel rendering can work really well and will only be noticed when you enlarge screenshots.